# Create a ASP.net login system based on a existing table?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-membership

Hi I currently have a table with names and surnames along with many details which will be appended towards MVC razor view , is it possible to create a login system which has a username thats based on the name and surname e.g. PeterJones or substring surname (jones99) within an exisiting table? 
The page will not have a registration form and only users which exist in the table will be able to login?

```
Table Example
-------------
First Name       Surname       Age

Peter            Jones         27
```

Can I create a login page which will use the first name and surname as values for the user login based on ASP.net membership or maybe a custom ASP.net login? Also could I append the users age to the view once peter jones has logged in?

Thank you

Comment: Have you checked any tutorial on ASP.NET authentication and the built-in membership providers? All of them include creating a custom login page. Most of them explain how to use a different database or table. In any case, what you show isn't membership, it's profile data

Comment: Check out ASP.NET Identity.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 things you shoud do.

First you have to erase the conection string that is user for create an temp table in app_data for the users that membership creates when you build the solution

Second in the membership class you have to modify the connection string to the connection string of your table base. And clean all base manipulations (create table, users, etc.)

Third also in membership class modify the [HttPost] of your Login Actionresult using your table base to compare the model received.

Comment: Thank you :)! Though I have decided to use Windows Authentication instead of Form Authentication now.